# JavaScript array is too small for c-w saving algorithm, what to do?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am implementing-w saving algorithm.
I implemented it and tested on small sets, works great. but when I input the large data, a problem occurs in the saving functions, which computes

```
   c(i,j) = c(start,i) + c(start,j) - c(i,j)
```

where c(i,j) is the cost for traveling from i to j. 
so I have to compute that first, but it turned out extremely big computations, I think it takes, since I have over 9000 locations in my data.

```
        9000+8999+ ...... +1 = 50,000,000 (near to that)
```

steps.

here is my function to compute savings.

```
this.calc_savings=function()
{
    var size = this.city_array.length;  //number of cities: greater than 9000 

    var start =start_city_index;
    for(var i=0; i < size; i ++)
    {
        if(i != start)
        {
            for(var j=i+1; j< size ; j++)
            {
                if(j !=start)
                {

                    var dis1 = this.get_distance(start,i); 
                    var dis2 = this.get_distance(start,j);
                    var dis3 = this.get_distance(j,i);

                    var cost = dis1 + dis2 - dis3;
                    var m_save = new saving(i,j,cost);
                    this.savings.push(m_save);
                  }

              }
          }

      }
  };
```

it  is reporting heap out of memmory error.

And I find out that without

```
   get_distance(...)
```

function, it works fast. 
that function computes distance between two earth coordinates, as shown

```
      function calcCrow(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) 
      { 
       var lati, latj, longi, longj;
       var q1, q2, q3, q4, q5;
       var m_pi = 3.14159265358979323846264; 
       lati = m_pi * lat1 / 180.0;
       latj = m_pi * lat2 / 180.0;

       longi = m_pi * lon1 / 180.0;
       longj = m_pi * lon2 / 180.0;

       q1 = Math.cos (latj) * Math.sin(longi - longj);
       q3 = Math.sin((longi - longj)/2.0);
       q4 = Math.cos((longi - longj)/2.0);

       q2 = Math.sin(lati + latj) * q3 * q3 - Math.sin(lati - latj) * q4 * q4;
       q5 = Math.cos(lati - latj) * q4 * q4 - Math.cos(lati + latj) * q3 * q3;

       var dis_meter =  (6378388.0 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(q1*q1 + q2*q2), q5) + 1.0);
       return dis_meter / 1000;
       };
```

which is called by

```
   this.get_distance=function(first,next)
   {
     var first_city,next_city;
     first_city = this.city_array[first];
     next_city = this.city_array[next];


    return   Math.floor(calcCrow(first_city.x, first_city.y, next_city.x, next_city.y));

    };
```

thes saving is defined as

```
     var saving = function( x_int, y_int,value) 
     {
      this.x =x_int ;   //latitude
      this.y =y_int ;   //longitude
      this.value = value; 
     };
```

so,what should I do?

Any suggestions?

Comment: What makes you think that a JavaScript array cannot hold 100,000 elements?

Comment: I think the real problem is that the algorithm you're implementing has an expected running time proportional to the square of the number of elements. That's going to take a while in any programming environment.

Comment: The maximum length of an array is 2^32-1, should be enough for the most of the use cases?

Comment: @Teemu just tested an array. Seems the real reason for my program is so slow is "get_distance" which computes the distance between two coordinates. but I cannot avoid compute these, have to do somewhere

Comment: @alim what does your `getDistance()` code look like? Sometimes, with some algorithms, working with the square of the distance is as good as working with the actual distance, which saves a square root computation. (You can't always do that though.)

Comment: What is the value of `size` and can we see the code for get_distance?

Comment: @Pointy updated the question with that function. :)  it has many math stuff, maybe I should switch to square distance which should be much faster.

Comment: size = 9875. quite big :(

Comment: @Pointy switched to square distance function, but still out of memory error occurred.

Comment: @alim, *heap out of memory* sounds to me like you're using a recursion somewhere. Please update the question and include the implementation of `get_distance()`, and every function it calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of calls to `get_distance` *a lot*, by simply caching the results, since I assume that these Values don't change during one loop.

```
this.calc_savings = function(){
    var size = this.city_array.length;  //number of cities: greater than 9000 

    var startDistances = this.city_array.map((city,i) => i === start_city_index? 0: this.get_distance(start_city_index, i));

    for(var i=0; i < size; ++i){
        if(i === start_city_index) continue;
        var dis1 = startDistances[i];

        for(var j=i+1; j<size; ++j){
            if(j === start_city_index) continue;

            var dis2 = startDistances[j];
            var dis3 = this.get_distance(j, i);
            var cost = dis1 + dis2 - dis3;
            this.savings.push(new saving(i, j, cost));
        }
    }
  };
```

maybe you can even cache `startDistances` as long as `start_city_index` doesn't change; that would reduce the cost to compute even more.

If you include your implementation of `get_distance` and `new saving()`, there could be even more improvements possible.

**Edit:** I just realized that we're talking about cities, and that they don't move that much ;) so the distances are pretty static. You can precompute them once and cache em all; that's not even a big overhead, since you already have to do this in a single call to `calc_savings`. This would reduce your cost to call `get_distance` to a single lookup at an Array. Although, it might have quite a memory impact *(9000 values -> 40495500 possible combinations -> ~155MB to store that many ints)*

```
//Beware, code is untested
this.init_cache = function(){
    var rad = Math.PI / 180;
    var size = this.city_array.length;
    var _distances = this._distances = Array(size * (size-1) / 2);
    var _offsets = this._offsets = Array(size);

    for(var i = 0, k = 0; i<size; ++i){
        _offsets[i] = k;
        var a = this.city_array[i],
            lat1 = a.x * rad, 
            lon1 = a.y * rad;

        for(var j = i+1; j<size; ++j){
            var b = this.city_array[j],
                lat2 = b.x * rad, 
                lon2 = b.y * rad,

                q1 = Math.cos(lat2) * Math.sin(lon1 - lon2),
                q3 = Math.sin((lon1 - lon2)/2),
                q4 = Math.cos((lon1 - lon2)/2),

                q2 = Math.sin(lat1 + lat2) * q3*q3 - Math.sin(lat1 - lat2) * q4*q4,
                q5 = Math.cos(lat1 - lat2) * q4*q4 - Math.cos(lat1 + lat2) * q3*q3,

                dist = 6378388 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(q1*q1 + q2*q2), q5) + 1;

            _distances[k++] = Math.floor( dist / 1000 );
        }
    }
};

this.get_distance = function(i, j){
    if(i === j) return 0;
    if(j < i) i^=j, j^=i, i^=j; //swap i and j
    this._distances || this.init_cache(); //just ensuring that cache is initialized when using it.
    return this._distances[ this._offsets[i] + j-i-1 ]
};

this.calc_savings = function(){
    var size = this.city_array.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < size; i ++){
        if(i === start_city_index) continue;
        var dis1 = this.get_distance(start_city_index,i); 

        for(var j = i+1; j < size; j++){
            if(j === start_city_index) continue;

            var dis2 = this.get_distance(start_city_index,j);
            var dis3 = this.get_distance(j,i);
            var cost = dis1 + dis2 - dis3;

            this.savings.push(new saving(i,j,cost));
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: I included these codes and reading your answer to understand it. :)

Comment: The third line computes all distance from start to other cities, then later use it again, I got it.  thanks.  it would be great if you could teach me more possible improvements.